# Immediate Subtraction in MIPS Assembly

Tags: ассемблер

задача: вычесть из 0xC8 0x98, используя immidiate

я знаю, что subi не существует, поэтому написала:

```
LUI $2, 0x98
NOR $3, $2, $0
ADDI $4, $3, 1
ADDI $5, $4, 0xC8
```

Ответ получается неверный. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Comment: Математически (если забыть о MIPS) алгоритм выглядит правильным, а ставить SPIM очень не хочется. Какой получается результат и как вы о нём узнаёте?

Comment: Я использую SIM-PL (учебная программа для моделирования систем цифровых логических вентелей, разных архитектур компьютеров) и в ней отображается, какие значения записались в какие регистры на каждом шаге выполнения программы. В $3 - FF67FFFF, в $4 - FF680000, в $5 - FF6800C8. То есть ошибка на этапе NOR. Я предполагаю, что это связано с приведением 16-ти бит к 32-м, но разобраться конкретно никак не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в первой же инструкции и расползается дальше.

`LUI`. Расшифруйте: *Load **Upper** Immediate*.
Загружает указанное значение в **старшие** байты регистра.

Вам нужно загружать значение в **младшие**, с помощью `ORI` или `ADDI` с нулём.

Comment: Поняла и исправила - задача решена. Спасибо большое.